# about select query, one table multiple result

Tags: sql, select

I searched before asking my question:

I have two tables.

Table **info**:

```
no    | name
1     | david
2     | kang
```

Table **info_kill**:

```
no   | staffno | skillno
------------------------
1    |    1    |    1
2    |    2    |    1
3    |    2    |    2
4    |    2    |    3
```

`staffno` in `info_skill` table and `no` in `info` table is foreign key.

I want to get:

1. `name` contains 'ka'
2. have `skillno` 1, 2, 3.

so, this is my sql,

```
SELECT a.NAME
FROM   (SELECT no,
               NAME
        FROM   info
        WHERE  NAME LIKE '%ka%') AS a
       INNER JOIN info_skill AS b
               ON a.no = b.staffno
       INNER JOIN info_skill AS c
               ON a.no = c.staffno
       INNER JOIN info_skill AS d
               ON a.no = d.staffno
WHERE  b.skillno = '1'
       AND c.skillno = '2'
       AND d.skillno = '3'
```

what I wonder is this part.

```
       INNER JOIN info_skill AS b
               ON a.no = b.staffno
       INNER JOIN info_skill AS c
               ON a.no = c.staffno
       INNER JOIN info_skill AS d
               ON a.no = d.staffno
WHERE  b.skillno = '1'
       AND c.skillno = '2'
       AND d.skillno = '3'
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.name 
from info a
inner join info_skill as b on a.no = b.staffno
where b.skillno in (1,2,3)
and name like '%ka%'
group by a.name
having count(distinct b.skillno) = 3
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/bd86b/1)

Comment: Thanks for answer. but where syntax is must be 'and'. i know 'in' is 'or'............

Comment: Have you tried it? The `having` clause makes sure to take only having all 3.

Comment: yes. i have tried. but i get same result 'in (1, 2, 3, 4)' and 'in (1,2,3)'. 1, 2, 3, 4 result also kang.......

Comment: @noDisplayName: I am aware of code formatting and I format it exactly the way I like it. So please do not change other users code only if you thing your code style is better than others

Comment: @juergend - Apologies and rolledback

Comment: oh, i am sorry. i think only where clause. i thought before sleep, i did not fix having clause. also i saw sql syntax like yours, i think where in is or, so this syntax is no my answer. but now i know because your kind explain. so Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT I.name
FROM info I
    JOIN info_skill S
         ON I.no = S.staffno
WHERE I.name LIKE'%ka%" AND
      S.skillno=1 OR
      S.skillno=2 OR
      S.skillno=3
```

This means:

- You join the two tables following the foreign key
- Then you search for any name containing *ka* word using `LIKE %ka%`
- Now, you need to check if skillno is equal to 1, 2 or 3

If this is not what you need exactly, then please make your question more clear by explaining what you are looking for exactly.